# How to update multiple sql rows where table 1's ID is equal to table 2's ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

*Application has no user input, nor will it be live on the web, so sql injection is not a threat*

**My Application**

This application is supposed to send multiple addresses from 1 table to Google's geocoder API and store the returned latitudes and longitudes inside a second table for later use.The API has a maximum of 2500 requests per day.

**What the problem is**

When I run my program with no limmits, there are only a few rows (about 20) that get updated out of 2500 rows that are supposed to get updated. When I limit my program to only update 10 rows to avoid hitting the API limit, no changes happen. Most of the rows that do update when I allow 2500 requests are updated with the correct value with the exception of a few, I'm not to worried about that right now I think those are just bad results from the geocoder.

**What I have so far**

I have 2 strings strLat and strLong that hold lattitudes and longitudes retrieved from google geocoder API.

```
string strLat = myCoordenates.Results[3].Geometry.Location.Lat.ToString();
string strLong = myCoordenates.Results[3].Geometry.Location.Lng.ToString();
```

I also have my attempt to update my database with them. This has been changed and manipulated many times, and i think the problem is likely to do with this part of my code.

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(context))
   {
     myConnection.Open();
     string strQueryUpdate = "UPDATE WEB_ARENA_GEO SET Lat = '" + strLat + "', Lng = '" + strLong + "'" + "WHERE ARENA_ID='" + row.ARENA_ID + "'";
     SqlCommand myCommandUpdate = new SqlCommand(strQueryUpdate, myConnection);
     myCommandUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

In my data base table 1 holds address data it has an Pk ID as well as a column called ADDRESS_ID, and then address is broken up like ADDRESS,CITY,ST,ZIP...ETC,  table 2 holds the latitudes and longitudes and also has that same ADDRESS_ID table with the same equal values, currently most of the lats and lngs are 0.00 and it is of type decimal.

***Table 1***

|--PKid--| ADDRESS_ID| ADDRESS | CITY..etc
|124246| 70-00002913  | 112 bill st. | bob town

***Table 2***

|  ADDRESS_ID  | Lat | Lng |
| 70-00002913  | 0.00| 0.00|

**Entire Update Controller**

```
    //GET: /TABLE2/Update/

    public ActionResult Update(string id)
    {
        IEnumerable<TABLE1> table1 = db.TABLE1;
        IEnumerable<TABLE2> table2 = db.TABLE2;
        string context = "my database context here";

        foreach (var row in table1.AsEnumerable().Take(10)) 
        {

            string strAddr = row.ADDRESS + "," + row.CITY + "," + row.ZIP + "," + row.COUNTRY;

            GoogleMapsDll.GeoResponse myCoordenates = new GoogleMapsDll.GeoResponse();
            myCoordenates = GoogleMapsDll.GoogleMaps.GetGeoCodedResults(strAddr);
            if (myCoordenates.Results != null && myCoordenates.Results.Length > 3)
            {
                string strLat = myCoordenates.Results[3].Geometry.Location.Lat.ToString();
                string strLong = myCoordenates.Results[3].Geometry.Location.Lng.ToString();
                using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(context))
                    {
                        myConnection.Open();
                        string strQueryUpdate = "UPDATE WEB_ARENA_GEO SET Lat = '" + strLat + "', Lng = '" + strLong + "'" + "WHERE ADDRESS_ID='" + row.ADDRESS_ID + "'";
                        SqlCommand myCommandUpdate = new SqlCommand(strQueryUpdate, myConnection);
                        myCommandUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

***If any other info would be helpful please simply ask in the comments and i will do my best to provide***

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what it is that you don't know how to do here?   Is it using a JOIN in an UPDATE?

Comment: I need to be able to update the rows in table 2 with the correct lat and lng that match with the same ID in table 1

Comment: yeah, you need to parameterize your update script

Comment: Will look into that, but will that also fix my issue were not all my rows are updating? but instead only a few select rows in my entire application?

Comment: There is not going to be any user input so i don't really have to worry about injection,

Comment: Having a SqlConnection in the same code as a Response.Redirect...just hurt my eyes.

Comment: Oh right, i took that out a long time ago and forgot to update the question, will do right away. I'm still new to C# and asp.net-mvc but i'm learning! and fairly new to computer code in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your where condition is defined incorrectly.  You are currently sending the following where:

```
 "WHERE'" + row.ADDRESS_ID + " = '" + row1.ADDRESS_ID + "'
```

This is basically comparing the actual id values against eachother.  I believe that you need to modify your query to be as follows:

```
 string strQueryUpdate = "UPDATE TABLE2 SET Lat = " + strLat + ", Lng = " + strLong + 
      " WHERE ADDRESS_ID='" + row.ADDRESS_ID + "'";
```

**UPDATE**

```
 var pageSize = 10;
 var totalPages = Math.Ceiling(table1.Count() / pageSize);

 for(var i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
      var addressesToProcess = table1.Skip(i * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
      foreach (var address in addressesToProcess) 
      {
           string strAddr = address.ADDRESS + "," + address.CITY + "," + address.ZIP + "," + address.COUNTRY;

           GoogleMapsDll.GeoResponse myCoordenates = new GoogleMapsDll.GeoResponse();
           myCoordenates = GoogleMapsDll.GoogleMaps.GetGeoCodedResults(strAddr);
           if (myCoordenates.Results != null && myCoordenates.Results.Length > 3)
           {
                string strLat = myCoordenates.Results[3].Geometry.Location.Lat.ToString();
                string strLong = myCoordenates.Results[3].Geometry.Location.Lng.ToString();
                using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(context))
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    string strQueryUpdate = "UPDATE WEB_ARENA_GEO SET Lat = '" + strLat + "', Lng = '" + strLong + "'" + "WHERE ADDRESS_ID='" + address.ADDRESS_ID + "'";
                    SqlCommand myCommandUpdate = new SqlCommand(strQueryUpdate, myConnection);
                    myCommandUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: I should have known this one but unfortunately it still hasn't fixed the issue, my rows still are not updating with lat and lngs.

Comment: can you confirm that for every address_id in table 1 there is a corresponding record in table 2 with the same address_id?

Comment: Yes , I can confirm this. 100% certain. ID's start at 70-00002913  and go up by 1 in order until 70-00005528

Comment: So from the looks of it ADDRESS_ID is a string column since it contains a hyphen (-).  I have updated the above update query to take that into consideration

Comment: Additionally, if the ADDRESS_IDs from table 1 exist in table 2 I do not believe that you need to loop over the rows in table 2 like you are doing above.  You should just loop over table 1 records to get the Lats and Longs and then once you have those values you should be able to execute the UPDATE by simply passing the table 1 ADDRESS_ID and the coordinates obtained.

Comment: This still is not updating, I am going to try and see if anything is not right with the returned jSon files from Google.

Comment: The ADDRESS_ID column is a var-char column.

Comment: I think that you may need to change the way that you are limiting your program to process ten at a time your foreach loop may be doing something strange the way that it is currently defined.  I updated my answer with a different approach.

Comment: Helpful answer , also, i changed the length > 3 to a 0 as well as the Results[3] to a 0, the varchar issue i solved by switching to a parameterized queries update method.